# Find $N = 1 + \frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{2+...}}}}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Please show how to solve this step by step, because I don't even have an idea to begin with.

$$N = 1 + \frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{2+...}}}}}$$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can see that the expression is found within itself. The trick is to manipulate that fact...
$$N+1 = 2 + \frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{2+...}}}}}$$
$$N+1 = 2+\frac{1}{N+1}$$
Can you solve the quadratic and continue from here?
P.S. You will get two values for $N$ by solving the quadratic. Only one of them is correct...

Comment: You can check your answer with me in the comments if you want to...

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: $$N = 1 + \cfrac{1}{2+\cfrac{1}{2+\cfrac{1}{2+\cfrac{1}{2+\cfrac{1}{\ddots}}}}}$$

$$N -1= \cfrac{1}{2+\color{blue}{\cfrac{1}{2+\cfrac{1}{2+\cfrac{1}{2+\cfrac{1}{\ddots}}}}}}$$

Notice that the blue part is also $N-1$.

$$N-1 = \frac{1}{2+\color{blue}{N-1}}$$

$$N-1 = \frac{1}{N+1}$$

It should be simple enough from here. Also, note that by inspection, $N > 1$, so it should be easy to discard an extraneous solution.